# How to fade / scatter sand on the floor around?

Tags: modeling, texturing, particles

I am trying to scatter sand so it fades out better onto the floor around it.
This is what I have know:
[image: This is what I have know:]

And this is what I want it to kind look like:

[image]

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You can use particle hairs and weight paint the amount to increase or decrease in a gradient.

Comment: on top of what @NascentSpace said I would also add a displacement modifier and apply the weight paint to it especially if you were making it on a larger scale because you would  want the sand to be ontop of itself

Answer (score 3):

You could use the image you show as a stencil to create a black and white image texture:

[image]

Then use this image texture as a mask in a material that mixes your background with a noisy material:

[image]